# what HTTP verb should I use for request some new data but not save them in data base?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I need to do 2 things :

1. Is to ask the server to create some problems and send their info to the client ( but not save them in DB )
2. client will answer some of them ( not all ) and then sending those problems with all pieces of information ( problem info and answer info ) to the server and save them in DB. ( the rest of problems are useless and will terminate in client and have no matter for server side )

so what HTTP verb should I use for each of them? ( and probably what URL )

Comment: I think POST and PUT make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want get a server to reply with some data to the client it sound like your just looking for a simple GET request. 
This question might be easier to address if you could add some concrete code though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is to ask the server to create some problems and send their info to
>   the client ( but not save them in DB )

This should be `GET` as you are requesting the server for some information and server is successfully processing it and serving the data.

> client will answer some of them ( not all ) and then sending those
>   problems with all pieces of information ( problem info and answer info
>   ) to the server and save them in DB. ( the rest of problems are
>   useless and will terminate in client and have no matter for server
>   side )

This should be `POST` as you are requesting the server to persist those problems.

Comment: First, HTTP is not a CRUD protocol for databases. Next, the semantics of `POST` are defined by the server implementor. It may be used to create, store, update, retrieve or even delete data. All [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) demands is that once a resource representation is created, a 201 response needs to be returned that contains a `Location` header pointing the client to the endpoint the newly created resource is available. There, however, is no indication whether the actual resource is stored in a DB, in a filesystem or litterally kept in memory.

Comment: I haven't say HTTP is a protocol for the DB. As per the question they have to persist it into the DB that why i mention DB otherwise the server is free to chose anything ( filesystem,db,in memory ). This is `POST` verb only because new content is created at the server if it's updated then `PUT` should be appropriate . Reading out the 3rd point from [RFC 7231 ](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) stated that `Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the
      origin server; and` .